# iCloud+Core Data, Data not loaded from iCloud at first time app is installed

Tags: ios, swift, icloud

I'm using Core data with iCloud to backup data when app is deleted or some other reason.
Syncing works fine and the datas are uploaded to iCloud correctly.
When we deleted app and re-installed app, the data doesn't display at all.
But when I push view controller and pop that view controller, the datas(which are downloaded from iCloud) are displayed.
It's really strange.

Here's my Core date helper source code.
https://gist.github.com/davidjonker/65c0f55101488bac9932874c1d0d2d98

Does anybody know solution?